# I get object HTMLSpanElement printed using find() with ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I have a file which has html code like :

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class='hour'>5pm</span>
            <span class='temp' data-code='10'></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class='hour'> 7pm</span>
            <span class='temp' data-code='8'></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class='hour'> 9pm</span>
            <span class='temp' data-code='14'></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The Jquery code:

```
 var url = file;
    $.get(
        url,
        function (data) {
            var html = $(data),
            hours = html.find('span.hour');
            $('.container').html('<p id="hour">'+ hours[0]+'</p>');

        }

    });
```

The html that the JS file linked to:

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

I get this inserted into the .contaner div : [object HTMLSpanElement]

I want to get the text inside each of the spans with class hour

Also , How can I get the value inside the second div with class temp , Which is data-code?

Comment: span tags arent closed properly. Missing a `<`

Comment: @void , I edited the question , It's written well in the file

Comment: `I want to get the text inside each of the spans with class hour` which text are you talking about here?

Comment: @void , 5pm , 7pm .. etc

Comment: `<span class='hour' 5pm></span>` shouldn't this be `<span class='hour'>5pm</span>`

Comment: @void, Yes sorry for typos

Comment: and where do you want to put these 5pm, 6pm?

Comment: inside the div with class container , $(.container).html(result);

Comment: What should be the result here, should it be comma separated values 5pm, 6pm. or what?

Comment: No , inside the container there will be <p> for each value , <div class=""container"> <p>5pm></p> <p>7pm</p> </div>

Comment: check the answer I have posted below..

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is what you are looking for.  (Check console)

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EQQJQL

Code from it

```
$(function() {

   var hourSpans = $('.hour')
   hourSpans.each(function() {
  console.log($( this ).html()); 
});

   var tempSpans = $('.temp')
   tempSpans.each(function() {
  console.log($( this ).attr('data-code')); 
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate on `span.hour`. Use `.append()` to append `<p>..</p>` in `.container`

```
function(data) {
  // Iterate on span.hour
  $(data).find('span.hour').each(function() {
    $('.container').append('<p id="hour">' + $(this).html() + '</p>');
  });
}
```